# I cannot get a boolean to change between true and false every second in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pygame, control-flow

I am making a game and in this game I want my character to bob from side to side however at the moment I cannot find a way to do this. I have used a boolean here to show which side he is on(Left) to try to make it simpler. I understand I am a noob, please don't rage if it is obvious.

This is my code:

```
LeftRight = True
Counter1 = 0


while True:
    if Counter1 <= 10:
        Left = True
    else:
        Left = False
    Counter1 += 1

    if Counter1 == 20:
        Counter1 = 0

    print (Left)
```

It has to be in a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

As @DominicKexel pointed out, the OP might not want to stop the whole program just to make the program wait for a second. To get over this problem, you can use `pygame.time.Clock()` as follows:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

timer = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60        #(60 frames per second)
i=0
left = True

while True:     #your main while loop
    timer.tick(FPS)
    if i < FPS:
        i += 1
    else:
        left = not left
        i = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from time import sleep

Left = True
while 1:
    Left = not Left  # flip the boolean
    sleep(1)  # wait one second
```

Comment: Consindering this has to happen in the main loop of a game, it's not very helpful to call `sleep` to stop the entire game for a full second (but I admit the question is not very clear about this).